# DataGridView equivalent of Listbox's IndexFromPoint

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, listbox

Is there an DataGridView equivalent of ListBox's IndexFromPoint method? I need it so that I can select a given cell when it is right-clicked, which it doesn't seem to detect normally, though left-clicks do select the cell. When I was using a ListBox, I achieved this through use of the IndexFromPoint method, which is why I bring it up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `CellContentClick` event. Make sure you verify the `RowIndex` is greater than 0 to handle when a user right clicks on a column header.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right && e.RowIndex >= 0)
     {
           dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
     }
 }
```